# Xml editor auto complete give wrong suggestion

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I know this problem have asked many times but i still cant solved my problem. My xml suddenly can't give suggestion, when i try use Ctrl+Space that give wrong suggestion like this
[image]

I have try

1. Invalidate Cache/Restart android studio
2. Delete cache folder inside c > users > windows > .gradle
3. Change setting like this
   [image]

But that way not works for me. Can anyone tell me how to solve this?

Here my gradle if someone need

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
    
    }
 }
 allprojects {
   repositories {
      google()
      jcenter()
      maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
   }
  }

  task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
  }

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

  android {
     useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
     compileSdkVersion 29

     defaultConfig {
       applicationId "com.fikri.sales"
       minSdkVersion 26
       targetSdkVersion 29
       versionCode 1
       versionName "1.0"
      }
       buildTypes {
         release {
         minifyEnabled false
         proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
        }

    }

    dependencies {
      implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
      implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
      implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
      implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.0'
      implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.1'
      implementation 'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.1.0'
      implementation 'com.budiyev.android:code-scanner:2.1.0'
      implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.4.0'
      implementation 'com.google.zxing:android-core:3.3.0'
      implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.3'
      implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
     }
```

Comment: This case already solved with reinstall android studio

Comment: Can you share the complete XML file?